# React components won't render; only seeing data-reactid=".0"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prototype

I'm creating my first React app, so apologies in advance. A newbie must learn as he goes.

But I'm a few hours into debugging, having gotten nowhere, and I'm hoping someone can clarify why this attempt to pass data into a React component, use prototype.map, and render a final component just isn't cutting it.

```
var imagedata = [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}];

var portraitPhoto = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
    <div className="test">
      <img src={"./build/assets/images/photos/square_raw/" + this.props.imagepath + ".jpg"} 
        className="full-width-portrait" />
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var portrait = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function(){
    return {
      data: imagedata
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    var portraitEach = this.props.data.map(function (imaged,i) {
          return (
                <div className="portrait2">
                    <portraitPhoto imagepath={imaged.id}/>
                </div>
          );
        });
    return (
       <div className="portrait-container">
            {portraitEach}
        </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <portrait/>,
  document.getElementById('portraits')
);
```

Comment: Your component names must start with a capital letter :)
Edit: [Source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your React components to have uppercase names. [React's help page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) says:

> React's JSX uses the upper vs. lower case convention to distinguish
>   between local component classes and HTML tags

Simply having this should be enough:

`var PortraitPhoto = React.createClass({ 
   ...
   ...
});`

A demo on jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rvgj5x72/).